# Cannot copy date from Bokeh DataTable

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I created a data table in bokeh that enables the user to filter the data (>40 columns and ~200 rows) by columns and rows. Here is the relevant portions of the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from datetime import date
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool,CustomJS, Div, Legend, LegendItem,DatetimeTickFormatter, CDSView, GroupFilter,TabPanel, Tabs, MultiChoice,DateRangeSlider, CustomJSFilter, Button
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select, DataTable, TableColumn, HTMLTemplateFormatter, FileInput,DateFormatter
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, layout
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap, factor_mark
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox 
import traceback


filtered_table_data=df

filtered_table_data["Date"]=filtered_table_data["Date"].dt.date

filtered_table_source= ColumnDataSource(data=filtered_table_data)

filtered_table_cols=[]

filtered_table_cols.append(TableColumn(field="Date", title="Date", width=150, visible=True, formatter=DateFormatter()))
for col in filtered_table_data.columns[2:]:
    filtered_table_cols.append(TableColumn(field=col, title=col, width=150, visible=False))
    
slider=DateRangeSlider(title="Select Date Range", value=(date(2022,12,19),date.today()), start=date(2022,12,19),end=date.today())
    
custom_filter = CustomJSFilter(args=dict(filtered_table_source=filtered_table_source, slider=slider), code='''
    var indices = [];
    var min=slider.value[0]
    var max=slider.value[1]
    

    for (var i = 0; i < filtered_table_source.get_length(); i++){
        if (filtered_table_source.data['Date'][i] >= min && filtered_table_source.data['Date'][i] <= max)
        {
            indices.push(true);
        } 
        else 
        {
            indices.push(false);
        }
    }
    return indices;
''')

filtered_table_view=CDSView(source=filtered_table_source, filters=[custom_filter])
filtered_table=DataTable(source=filtered_table_source, view=filtered_table_view, columns=filtered_table_cols, width=1850,height=500,fit_columns=False, selectable="checkbox")

multi_choice = MultiChoice(value=[], options=df.columns[2:-1].tolist(), title='Select elements:')

callback2 = CustomJS(args=dict(multi_choice=multi_choice, filtered_table=filtered_table), code="""
    for (var i=0; i<filtered_table.columns.length; i++)
    {
     
     filtered_table.columns[i].visible=false
     if (filtered_table.columns[i].field=="Date")
     {
         
         filtered_table.columns[i].visible=true
     }      
     for (var j=0; j<multi_choice.value.length;j++)
     {
          
             if (filtered_table.columns[i].field==multi_choice.value[j])
             {
                 
                 filtered_table.columns[i].visible=true
             }         
     }
    }             
""")

callback3 = CustomJS(args=dict(filtered_table_source=filtered_table_source), code="""
    filtered_table_source.change.emit()  
""")

multi_choice.js_on_change("value",callback2) 

slider.js_on_change('value', callback3)

l=layout([multi_choice, filtered_table],
          [slider])

show(l)
```

Now I would like the user to be able to copy and paste their selection into Excel. The issue is when rows are copied into Excel the Date column is completely blank

Selected rows: [image]

Copied data in Excel:
[image]

Comment: Rather, it looks like the blank column is the bool checkbox column and the date column is the "1.68E+12" values (Bokeh datetime values are represented by floating point epoch timestamps)

Comment: @bigreddot Oh I see! You are correct. But is there a way excel can convert it into date? When I try to change the format excel replaces the number with a bunch of #

Comment: @Gingerhaze If the `#` isn't allready a date (try to click into the field) excel offers functions to tranform a number into a date. Hope this [guide](https://www.extendoffice.com/excel/formulas/excel-convert-number-to-date.html) helps.